# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent NodeJS Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I keep getting can't set headers after they are sent, i think the problem is because i am calling res.status(400).json 2 times, but i don't know how to do it other than this since i am new with node and mongoose.

```
createItem: function (req, res) {
    var item = new Items();
    item.name = req.body.name;
    item.save(err => {
      if (err) {return res.status(400).json({'error': err});}
      for(let i of req.body.subItems){
        var sub = new SubItems();
        sub.name = i.name;
        sub.item = item._id;

        sub.save(err => {
          if (err) {return res.status(400).json({'error': err});}
        })
        item.subItems.push(sub);
        item.save(err => {
          if (err) {return res.status(400).json({'error': err});}
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).send(item);
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Yep, it is because you are returning the `res.status(400).json({'error': err});` rather than just finishing that function there. By calling `res.status().json()` or calling `res.send()` or similar will already end the function and send the response to the caller.

By returning it in the callback, it will return to the caller function which  will still be running and will go into `res.status(200).send(item);` but since you have already set it as `res.status(400).json({'error': err});` the headers have already been set and hence will throw an error.

To fix this, as previously stated, you can just write `res.status(400).json({'error': err});` with no return as this will just finish the request. Alternatively, you can use the `next` callback function and have a universal error handler at the end to deal with errors. Note, that you will have to add `next` as a parameter into `createItem function` if you are doing this method.

**Code by removing returns**

```
createItem: function (req, res) {
var item = new Items();
item.name = req.body.name;
item.save(err => {
  if (err) {res.status(400).json({'error': err});}
  for(let i of req.body.subItems){
    var sub = new SubItems();
    sub.name = i.name;
    sub.item = item._id;

    sub.save(err => {
      if (err) {res.status(400).json({'error': err});}
    })
    item.subItems.push(sub);
    item.save(err => {
      if (err) {res.status(400).json({'error': err});}
    });
   }
  return res.status(200).send(item);
  });
 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i changed my code but i still got the same error, after some reflexion i think the problem is related to the return 'res .status.json' inside the loop for.

Comment: I don't know if you resolved the issue, but I realised what the actual error is. It is because you are not use else after if and this is runs on callbacks i.e. asynchronous. So it is going to send `return res.status(200).send(item);` before `{res.status(400).json({'error': err});}` which will get run after that item has been saved